# How to upload a file and populate parts of the website with its content?

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, flask

There are related questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27628053/uploading-and-downloading-files-with-flask) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46925487/upload-read-write-excel-file-in-python-flask) but they don't solve my problem.

Let's say I have a file `testdata.csv` like this:

```
A,B
1,3
2,4
```

and I want the user allow to upload the file and then - just for simplicity - display its content on the same page without affecting any other elements on this page. So my desired outcome would look like this:

[image]

How would I do this? I found a couple of approaches that use a `form` to load the file and send its (modified) content back (to e.g. download it) but I struggle to find a solution to pass the `JSON` response back to modify the page (here: add the table).

This is my entire code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json

# Initialize the Flask application
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/_get_table', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def get_table():

    # how to catch the file here and send its content back?
    # file = ????
    # print(file)
    df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2], "B": [3, 4]})

    return jsonify(my_table=json.loads(df.to_json(orient="split"))["data"],
                   columns=[{"title": str(col)} for col in json.loads(df.to_json(orient="split"))["columns"]])

    # if I use a form, I can use
    # file = request.files['myfile']
    # however, how do I then send the JSON response?

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and my `index.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">
        <h3 class="text-center text-muted">Some great stuff</h3>
      </div>

      <hr class="mb-4">

      <div class="custom-file">
         <input id="myfile" name="myfile" type="file" class="custom-file-input">

         <label for="myfile" class="custom-file-label">
           Choose file...
         </label>
      </div><br><br>

      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="upload_document">Upload and process!</button>

      <hr class="mb-4">

      <table id="pretty_table" class="table table-striped"></table>

      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

          var table = null;
          $('#upload_document').bind('click', function() {

            $.getJSON('/_get_table', {
              // what to pass here?
            }, function(data) {

              if (table !== null) {
                table.destroy();
                table = null;
                $("#pretty_table").empty();
              }
              table = $("#pretty_table").DataTable({
                data: data.my_table,
                columns: data.columns

              });
            });
            return false;
          });

          $('.custom-file-input').on('change', function() {
             let fileName = $(this).val().split('\\').pop();
             $(this).next('.custom-file-label').addClass("selected").html(fileName);
          });
        });
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Search how to upload file with ajax (not hard to find lots of results). Will need to use FormData API and $.ajax instead of simple `getJSON`

Comment: @charlietfl: Ok, thanks for the comment. You mean, something like [this](https://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-ajax-submit-a-multipart-form/)? Never used this before; let's see if I get it to work... If it is not too much work for you, I would highly appreciate an answer (the html/jquery part would be sufficient), thanks!

Comment: Yes...that is the basics in that link

Comment: @charlietfl: Ok, these things always give me a headache, but I will try... :)

Comment: An alternative is to use FileReader API and parse the csv in browser

Comment: @charlietfl: have never used that either, but will take a look.  Would it be much work for you to write the FormData jquery part? (just asking ;) )

Comment: It's already written in that link. Simply a matter of matching selector to your form

Comment: @charlietfl: Thanks, that got me on the right track; I added an answer below which contains all required files to obtain the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@charlietfl in the comments and [this link](https://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-ajax-submit-a-multipart-form/) got me on the right track. One can use `FormData` and then an `.ajax` call to achieve the desired outcome. So the important parts of above's link are (the complete files can be found below):

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="fileUploadForm">
    <div class="custom-file">
       <input id="myfile" name="myfile" type="file" class="custom-file-input">

         <label for="myfile" class="custom-file-label">
             Choose file...
         </label>
    </div>
</form>
```

and

```
// Get form
var form = $('#fileUploadForm')[0];

// Create an FormData object
var data = new FormData(form);
```

and

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        url: "/_get_table",
        data: data,
        processData: false,
```

The `processData: false,` is important to prevent jQuery form transforming the data into a query string as explained in the link above.

On the flask site, we can then easily retrieve the file by doing:

```
file = request.files['myfile']

df = pd.read_csv(file)
```

which turns the `.csv` into a pandas dataframe. Clearly, there should be checks etc before doing this.

The entire `HTML` page `index_formdata.html` would look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">
        <h3 class="text-center text-muted">Some great stuff</h3>
      </div>

      <hr class="mb-4">
      <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="fileUploadForm">
        <div class="custom-file">
           <input id="myfile" name="myfile" type="file" class="custom-file-input">

           <label for="myfile" class="custom-file-label">
             Choose file...
           </label>
        </div>
      </form><br><br>

      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="upload_document">Upload and process!</button>

      <hr class="mb-4">

      <table id="pretty_table" class="table table-striped"></table>

      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var table = null;

            $("#upload_document").click(function (event) {

                //stop submit the form, we will post it manually.
                event.preventDefault();

                // Get form
                var form = $('#fileUploadForm')[0];

                // Create an FormData object
                var data = new FormData(form);

                // disabled the submit button
                $("#upload_document").prop("disabled", true);

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                    url: "/_get_table",
                    data: data,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    cache: false,
                    timeout: 600000,
                    success: function (data) {

                      if (table !== null) {
                        table.destroy();
                        table = null;
                        $("#pretty_table").empty();
                      }
                      table = $("#pretty_table").DataTable({
                        data: data.my_table,
                        columns: data.columns

                      });
                      $("#upload_document").prop("disabled", false);

                    },
                    error: function (e) {

                        alert(e.responseText);
                        console.log("ERROR : ", e);
                        $("#upload_document").prop("disabled", false);

                    }
                });

            });
            $('.custom-file-input').on('change', function() {
               let fileName = $(this).val().split('\\').pop();
               $(this).next('.custom-file-label').addClass("selected").html(fileName);
            });

        });
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

the flask file as follows:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json

# Initialize the Flask application
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index_formdata.html')


@app.route('/_get_table', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def get_table():

    # catch file from the form; if you have several files, just make several requests (access by name)
    file = request.files['myfile']

    df = pd.read_csv(file)

    return jsonify(my_table=json.loads(df.to_json(orient="split"))["data"],
                   columns=[{"title": str(col)} for col in json.loads(df.to_json(orient="split"))["columns"]])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and the `testdata.csv` file

```
A,B,C
1,3,123
2,4,456
```